# Full search not working with linq Skip Take in .net 5.0;

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

In my project I have pagination.

My code looks like:

```
        var queryable = _context.Projects.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).AsQueryable();          
    
        queryable = ProjectListExtension.Sort(request, queryable);
        queryable = ProjectListExtension.Search(request, queryable);
        
        var projects = await queryable
            .Skip(request.Offset ?? 0).Take(request.Limit ?? 50)
            .ProjectToListAsync<ProjectListForUiDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        return new ProjectsList
        (
            projects,
            await queryable.CountAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
        );
```

My extension method for search looks like:

```
public static class ProjectListExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<Project> Search(ProjectListQuery query, IQueryable<Project> queryable) =>
        query switch
        {
            {Search:not null} => queryable.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(query.Search.ToLower()) || x.Organization.Name.ToLower().Contains(query.Search.ToLower())),
            _ => queryable
        };
}
```

I try offset 1 and limit 3, simply I'd like search from 2nd page element which exists in 1st page.

In result it returns empty result, but in total Count I can see 1 (which means found this data). I don't quite understand I suppose paging should be last part of operation

P.S. We have 5 result
1st page
element1
element2
element3
2nd page
element4
element5

I am on 2nd page, and when I type element1 I'd like to see result.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw sql?

Comment: @TheGeneral not really, but just curious what can be wrong here as it returns correct total count

Comment: Check your `request.Offset`, if it is 1 or greatest, you will not have records. For first page `Skip` should be `0`.